# How to make auto zoom when GeoJSON file is added on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, php, zoom

I want it to auto zoom / zoom to center when any GeoJSON file is loaded on a Leaflet map. Help please.

```
$.getJSON("{{asset("storage/upload/shapefiles/districts/atd_district_level.geojson")}}",function(data){
                // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
                L.geoJson(data, {

                    style: {color: "#999", weight: 2, fillColor: "#00ad79", fillOpacity: .6},

                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                        layer.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties['DISTRICT'])
                    }

                }).addTo(map);
            });
```

I am new with Leaflet maps.

Comment: There's no such thing as a GeoJSON shapefile, they are both data formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep a reference to the geojson layer you can get its bounds, and then fit the map to it.

```
$.getJSON("{{asset("storage/upload/shapefiles/districts/atd_district_level.geojson")}}",function(data){
                // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
                jsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {

                    style: {color: "#999", weight: 2, fillColor: "#00ad79", fillOpacity: .6},

                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                        layer.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties['DISTRICT'])
                    }

                })
               jsonLayer.addTo(map);
               map.fitBounds(jsonLayer.getBounds());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a varible name to `L.geoJson` tag. call it via fitBounds

```
var cable=L.geoJson(cable, {
    style: Cablestyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeatureCable
   }).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(cable.getBounds());
```